# HTML5 Audio: Using both oncanplay and oncanplaythrough events for audio

Tags: javascript, html, events, audio

I was told to use both events `oncanplay` and `oncanplaythrough` events because `oncanplay` can be unreliable in some browsers:

In my code, I am only using the `oncanplay` event. How can I set up my code so that I am able to use both events, as I was told?

```
// player is an HTML5 Audio Element

player.oncanplay = function () {
        if (value.value !== "") {
            canPlay = true;
            playPauseIcon(true);
        }
    };
```

My complete code listing is here: https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/142/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concerned about the `canplay` event not firing, you can use both the `canplaythrough` and `canplay` events in conjunction. Based on your code, it should be possible to more-or-less reuse the same event handler for both events.

Consider the following changes, namely the use of `addEventListener()` to register handlers for both events, and the declaration of a common handler function with slightly revised logic:

```
// Define a common handler function that will be reused for
// both events
function playerMediaPlayable() {

    // Add canPlay !== true to prevent playPauseIcon() being
    // called a second time if 'canplaythrough' fires after 'canplay'
    if (value.value !== "" && canPlay !== true) {

        canPlay = true;
        playPauseIcon(true);
    }
}

// Use playerMediaPlayable handler for both events
player.addEventListener('canplay', playerMediaPlayable);
player.addEventListener('canplaythrough', playerMediaPlayable);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Can you provide an updated jsfiddle with that implemented in the code please? And thank you for the information. https://jsfiddle.net/vhgL96se/142/

Comment: @MaryJaneSmith sure thing - here you go https://jsfiddle.net/ez02nsxg/ All the best with your project :)

Comment: What if I set it up this way instead? Would this be a better way to do it? https://jsfiddle.net/Lyj70doe/3/

Comment: @MaryJaneSmith just tried it but it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Try again, hit set and the audio should be playing. ["canplay", "canplaythrough"]; https://jsfiddle.net/Lyj70doe/15/ If the audio isn't playing, what browser are you using? It works for me in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Ah yes - that works. Looks like a good approach, though I'm not sure there are any other event types that you would add to that array, that would benift from the same event handler. Good idea though :)